# Mass IP domain mapping

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, internal-dns

I would like to have for each private IP a mapping like this:

ip-192-168-0-1.domain IN A 192.168.0.1

I am using bind9. Is there any way to use a regex to do this? I know that bind supports wildcard records but I was unable to find any example with regular expressions.

Do I have to add a record for each IP?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`$GENERATE`](http://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind9/cur/9.8/doc/arm/Bv9ARM.ch06.html#id2598552) statement to define multiple records which only differ by an iterator. For example:

```
$GENERATE 1-255 ip-192-168-0-$.domain A 192.168.0.$
```

**Edit:** It doesn't seem possible to nest `$GENERATE` statements, so if you need to build records for more than a /24 you'll need a separate line for each /24. You can of course use a script to generate this:

```
for I in `seq 0 255`; do
    echo "\$GENERATE 1-255 ip-192-168-$I-\$.domain A 192.168.$I.\$"
done >> myzone
```

Comment: How can I use this to map 192.168.0.0/16?

Comment: I'm sure from this information you can find this in the manual and construct the appropriate line your your situation.

Comment: I read the manual before commenting but I found this 'can be used to easily generate the sets of records required to support sub /24 reverse delegations'

Comment: @RobertDolca Edited.